# Make an element equidistant to the top of the page and the next div

Tags: html, css, distance

I'd like to have "Anagoor" equidistant from the top of the page (the menu) and the video right below it. This il the link to the page: https://civitonia.com/26839343

HTML (for Anagoor):

```
<div class="nomeartista">
<div grid-row="" grid-pad="2.5" grid-gutter="5">
    <div grid-col="1" grid-pad="2.5"></div>
    <div grid-col="10" grid-pad="2.5"><div class="">
    <svg class="colorSVG" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1949.3 759" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1949.3 759;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M213.9,737.7l-25.5-201.4h-73.7l-12.8,201.4H13.5l108-618L79.3,20.5h97.3l119.8,717.2H213.9z M116.6,516.6h68.8
        l-17.7-142.5L149,177.7h-10.8L116.6,516.6z"></path>
    <path d="M476.1,20.5h70.7v717.2h-69.7l-94.3-596.3H371l13.7,227l5.9,369.4h-69.7V20.5h69.7l94.3,596.3h11.8l-13.8-227L476.1,20.5z"></path>
    <path d="M771.7,737.7l-25.5-201.4h-73.7l-12.8,201.4h-88.4l108-618l-42.2-99.2h97.3l119.8,717.2H771.7z M674.5,516.6h68.8
        l-17.7-142.5l-18.7-196.5h-10.8L674.5,516.6z"></path>
    <path d="M976,425.3h121.8v19.6h-1c-20.6,0-24.5,3.9-24.5,23.6v279h-10.8l-25.6-114.9h-9.8c-11.8,77.5-36.3,114.9-80.5,114.9
        c-42.3,0-66.8-30.4-66.8-114.9V143.3c0-96.3,50.1-132.6,110-132.6c51.1,0,75.7,30.4,75.7,91.4c0,50.1-2,118.9-19.7,218.1h-74.7
        c68.8-147.4,75.6-185.7,75.6-213.2c0-21.6-15.7-29.5-57-29.5c-29.5,0-36.3,21.6-36.3,56v465.6c0,70.7,13.7,81.6,28.5,81.6
        c21.6,0,32.4-31.4,32.4-100.2V444.9H976V425.3z"></path>
    <path d="M1242.1,747.5c-67.8,0-105.1-30.4-105.1-114.9V143.3c0-96.3,53-132.6,116.9-132.6c68.8,0,105.2,30.4,105.2,114.9v489.3
        C1359.1,711.1,1306,747.5,1242.1,747.5z M1247,77.5c-29.4,0-36.3,21.6-36.3,56v465.6c0,70.7,19.6,81.6,43.2,81.6
        c25.6,0,31.5-21.7,31.5-56V159C1285.4,88.3,1266.7,77.5,1247,77.5z"></path>
    <path d="M1523.1,747.5c-67.8,0-105.2-30.4-105.2-114.9V143.3c0-96.3,53.1-132.6,117-132.6c68.7,0,105,30.4,105,114.9v489.3
        C1639.9,711.1,1586.9,747.5,1523.1,747.5z M1528,77.5c-29.5,0-36.4,21.6-36.4,56v465.6c0,70.7,19.7,81.6,43.3,81.6
        c25.5,0,31.4-21.7,31.4-56V159C1566.3,88.3,1547.6,77.5,1528,77.5z"></path>
    <path d="M1880.6,453.8l55,283.9h-74.7l-37.3-235.8c-4-24.6-20.6-37.3-51.1-23.6v259.4h-73.7V20.5h88.5
        c84.5,0,133.6,34.4,133.6,123.8v166c0,77.6-44.2,113-101.2,139.5l1,11.8L1880.6,453.8z M1772.5,87.3v364.5l18.6-7.8
        c44.2-18.7,56-40.3,56-74.7V168.9c0-63.8-17.7-81.5-66.8-81.5H1772.5z"></path>
</g>
</svg>
</div></div>
    <div grid-col="1" grid-pad="2.5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the video right after:

```
<div class="image-gallery" gid="7">
<iframe frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LX8Y4rMCO8g" allowfullscreen="" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player"></iframe>
</div>
```

The menu:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="TemporaryHome" rel="history" id="home">HOME</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="artista"> ARTISTƏ</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="gallery">GALLERY</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="news">NEWS</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="about">ABOUT US</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Search for flexbox and vertical centering an element to which you wind hundreds of solutions alone on SO.

Comment: Please show your relevant "*[mcve]*" code, HTML *and* CSS, in your question; don't separate the HTML into three chunks (and apparently in the wrong order) and then ask us to first put into the correct order, *and* recreate your CSS in order to reproduce your problem.